# I want to use Bearer Authentication in my custom policy Azure ad b2c IEF. I wanted to understand how to handle token expiration in policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, bearer-token, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

[image: 1]
This shows that I just have to pass authentication type and the token is stored under policy keys. how do i handle token expiration?

I wanted to understand token handling mechanism

Answer (score 0):

When the policy secret expires, replace it with a new one using the same name. One way to make it easier to manage is to make expiration date part of the policy. For example: B2C_1A_MyCertificate20251231. This is how you can name a certificate that expires on 2025-12-31.